# How to Store Vectors in Java? What's the Data Type?

Tags: java, vector

I just read [this](http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/07/linear-algebra-for-game-developers-part-1/) tutorial. It's about game development, and it basically says that I need to store acceleration, velocity, position as vectors to make game physics. Hope it makes sense! I need to choose data type now... for example I need to store values like...

> (3, 5, 2)
>
> (6, 2, 3)
>
> (2, 3)

Also, I will need to do addition and subtraction like this...

> (0, 1, 4) + (3, -2, 5) = (0 + 3, 1 - 2, 4 + 5) = (3, -1,9)

**What data type should I use in this situation?**

For one vector two integers (floats/doubles) maybe? Maybe array for one vector where where values are integers (floats/doubles)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you want three values (probably doubles):

```
public class Vector3
{
    private final double x;
    private final double y;
    private final double z;

    public Vector3(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public Vector3 plus(Vector3 other)
    {
        return new Vector3(x + other.x, y + other.y, z + other.z);
    }

    // etc
}
```

Note that I've made this immutable - which isn't always the best choice for performance (which may be relevant in your situation) but helps with readability.

Comment: But how can I store value (1, 2, 3) as integer? I see there three integers, but I need to store them in one value.

Comment: @daGrevis: You don't. You've got three values - store them as three values. You keep one reference to the object *containing* the three values. How much experience do you have of how classes and objects work in Java? It's going to be pretty important...

Comment: change Vector<double ... to Vector<Object

Comment: But what about arrays? Maybe I could do like: 'double[] position = { 2, -6 };'?

Comment: @mKorbel: I don't understand what you're talking about here, but I'm *not* talking about `java.util.Vector<E>`.

Comment: @daGrevis: I wouldn't use an array here - you know you've always got three values (x, y and z) so use them. If you want an array of vectors, you'd use `Vector3[]`.

Comment: Wait... I'm newbie in OPP...you say that I need to make new class for it, for example, class Ball, that have fields acceleration, velocity, position?

Comment: @daGrevis: Well I've *given* you the class for a vector with three values. You can use the same class for position, velocity and acceleration in. It seems unlikely that a single class would have the three values in it, mind you... but we don't know what you're really trying to do. Personally I would suggest that you do more basic Java development before trying for a game. Get the hang of the basics of the language using simple console apps.

Comment: upps thatnks sure its about Vectoring

Comment: @Jon Skeet No, it won't be necessary. I understand! Thanks for answer.

Comment: @John Skeet, upvote you answer is perfect. @deGrevis I suggest learning how OOP works, specifically classes and instances.

Comment: @AttackingHobo Then provide me some good article, because I know the basics. I don't know where to use them in real applications. That's all.

Comment: @daGrevis, you say you know the basics, but if you did, the answer that Jon Skeet posted would have made perfect sense. Knowing what a term is called is not knowing the basics, being able to use something in a live program is knowing the basics.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html I found this by searching "classes instances java" without quotes.

Comment: @AttackingHobo Okey, I don't know the basics then. Please, try to teach me! I want to learn. =P

Comment: @deGrevis check that link I posted up there.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [commons-math](http://commons.apache.org/math/) [`OpenMapRealVector`](http://commons.apache.org/math/api-2.2/org/apache/commons/math/linear/OpenMapRealVector.html) can be of use.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use generics:

```
public interface MathVector<T extends Number>
{
    MathVector<T> add(MathVector<T> addend);
    T innerProduct();
    // Vectors have more than this, but it makes the point
}
```